OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'model'. If you are trying from 'https://huggingface.co', make sure you don't have a local repo with the same name
OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'AniketArtani/deploytest'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'AniketArtani/deploytest' is the correct path to a directory containing all relevant.
Getting this error while loading model through hugging face model card and even through code too.
